# Regex on (My)SQL create statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, regex

> I am using an older version of a tool I like and am familiar using,
>   but it's not creating the right output in its create statement. 
>   Because this is going to be a repetitive task, I am making a little
>   web tool; making my target Regex in JaveScript.  I am looking to break
>   up the replacements in a few bits, but I think 1 line of regex will
>   get me going, I can then work backwards.

I am looking to replace the first `'BINARY(16)'` following the `'('` just after `Batch`(Or any word).  I am testing in RegexBuddy, I tried: `\(\s\w+\s(BINARY\(\d{1,2}\)[^,)])` as well as many other things, but no success.

```
CREATE TABLE Batch(
    batch_id               BINARY(16)    NOT NULL,
    batch_datetime         DATETIME,
    overhead_project_id    BINARY(16)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Using `ConvertMe.replace(/(FooStatement/gi, "INT(11)    NOT NULL    AUTO INCREMENT");`.
My end goal is to get to:  (I also have to fix some FLOATs and other INTs on other create statements)

```
CREATE TABLE Batch(
    batch_id               INT(11)    NOT NULL    AUTO INCREMENT,
    batch_datetime         DATETIME,
    overhead_project_id    INT(11)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Solution:  ConvertMe = ConvertMe.replace(/(((\s|\n|\r)*\w*\s+)(BINARY(\d{1,2})[^,]*)/gi, "$1INT(11)     NOT NULL     AUTO INCREMENT");

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are trying to match.  Just the BINARY(16) or the remainder of the line?

Comment: Remainder of the line, updated for clarity. ~TY

Comment: Your expression should be `\(\s+\w+\s+(BINARY\(\d{1,2}\)[^,)])`, but this still wont meet your requirements if the first binary field is not also the first field.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Add it below as an answer, don't just edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. i think it is what you are looking for

```
\(?[A-Za-z].+?(BINARY\([0-9]{1,2}\))
```

Comment: Helpful, but I am trying to match the first one after the ( - to fix the primary key first.  That returned all of them.  I guess we need to limit the times it matches binary to 1.  Also I changed it a bit:  `\(?BINARY\([0-9]{1,2}.*[^,)]`  I don't need to touch the column name (batch_id, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it, you don't need a complicated regex is not necessary for this, just a simple search/replace:

```
/BINARY\(16\)/INT\(11\)/g
```

---

To address your interest in the comments about adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` command, I would like to remind you that regular expressions are simply a tool for finding and/or replacing strings. What you describe is different; you want to do two searches and an insertion, with the insertion based on the first search. Don't make things complicated for yourself; do these steps separately.

1. Find `PRIMARY_KEY( * )`, extract the `*`
2. Search for the line containing the `*` string
3. At the end of that line, replace the `,` with `AUTO_INCREMENT,`.

Comment: I need to be able to add on AUTO INCREMENT at the end of the line for the PrimaryKey.  That will be helpful for the other parts though, TY.

Comment: @intellilogic - (a) Glad to help, if you found this (or any other answer) useful please vote up. (b) Adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` will be a second, and more complicated, process. Definitely perform them separately.

Answer (score 0):

use the following javascript:

```
var re = new RegExp("(\((\s|\n|\r)*\w*\s+)(BINARY\(\d{1,2}\)[^,]*)", "g");
var myArray = str.replace(re,"$1YOUR_REPLACEMENT" );
```

[online regex tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm?rp=%28%5C%28%28%5Cs%7C%5Cn%7C%5Cr%29%2a%5Cw%2a%5Cs%2b%29%28BINARY%5C%28%5Cd%7B1,2%7D%5C%29%5B%5E,%5D%2a%29&rf=g&me=4&ts=CREATE%20TABLE%20Batch%28%0A%20%20%20%20batch_id%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20BINARY%2816%29%20%20%20%20NOT%20NULL,%0A%20%20%20%20batch_datetime%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DATETIME,%0A%20%20%20%20overhead_project_id%20%20%20%20BINARY%2816%29%20%20%20%20NOT%20NULL,%0A%20%20%20%20PRIMARY%20KEY%20%28batch_id%29%0A%29ENGINE=INNODB;%0A)

Comment: Awesome, thank you and everyone else who helped.  I am too new to vote this answer up :(   End result:  ConvertMe = ConvertMe.replace(/(\((\s|\n|\r)*\w*\s+)(BINARY\(\d{1,2}\)[^,]*)/gi, "$1INT(11)     NOT NULL     AUTO INCREMENT");

Comment: yes $1 is '( batch_id' and $2 is empty, therefore I replace the whole match with '$1___YOURR_REPLACEMENT___', maybe there is a more clean solution but mine works